# Most straightforward way of running old java applets

Tags: java, applet

Many physical animation / simulation applets on the internet are decades old Java applets and it is extremely difficult to get them to work. What would be the best way to run a Java applet (which browsers do not allow)?

For example, I have a `.class` used in a `.htm`

```
<applet code="taylor.class" name="taylor" width="900" height="800">
    <param name="label" value="This string was passed from the HTML host.">
    <param name="background" value="008080">
    <param name="foreground" value="FFFFFF">
</applet>
```

How do I run this without being blocked by security things?

Comment: I don't actually have the code. I might only find the .class SOMETIMES

Comment: marked as duplicate... ok. where is the link to the other question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [appletviewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppletViewer) of the JDK. The appletviewer allows you to open the applet (via its URL) without the need to use a browser.

Comment: Note that you'll probably need an old version of Java.